# Why does meta have a Suggested Edits queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, meta

As far as I know, you can't suggest edits on Meta sites. So why does Meta SO have a review queue for [Suggested Edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits)?

Comment: Did you suggested any edit?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam I said in the first sentence, as far as I know, you can't do that. The "edit" button is just greyed out on meta sites.

Comment: Greyed mean you cannot click it?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam if you're under 2K, the edit button is indeed grayed out on meta

Comment: @Patrice I did not know that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Even though you cannot make suggested edits on regular posts on Meta, users with [< 20k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) *can* edit tag wikis through suggested edits.

As such, the review queue still needs to exist to review those tag wiki edits. If you have [10k or more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), you can see the [full review history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history) for the queue; notice that all those suggested edits are for tag wikis and tag wiki excerpts.

You need [at least 5k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) before you can review suggested edits on tag wikis.

Comment: Note that you need 10k to see anyone else's reviews in the review history.

Comment: @Servy: you can see it with 5k, but you cannot see reviews by others before you reach 10k.

Comment: Why can 2k rep users review edits that can only be initiated by >5k rep users, is that not a bit backwards?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: ? 2k rep users cannot review suggested edits to tag wikis, no.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The queue is available to me, it just shows nothing to be reviewed. Maybe I'm misunderstanding and it wont let me perform the reviews but technically lets me visit the queue. (it is visually distinct from the greyed out close and reopen meta queues, leading me to believe I could perform the reviews)

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: Yes, you can visit the queue from 2k onwards. There is just nothing to review because you cannot make suggested edits on regular posts. You won't see any tag wiki suggested edits until you get to 5k. You *can* suggest edits to tag wikis before you have 5k, however.

Answer (score -11):

> As far as I know, you can't suggest edits on Meta sites.

That is false.  You *can* suggest edits on meta sites.

> So why does Meta SO have a review queue for Suggested Edits?

We have a review queue for suggested edits to review the edits that are suggested.

Comment: You cannot suggest edits *on regular posts* when you have < 2k reputation. The queue is only there for tag wiki edits.